# bash anti quote in anti quote

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to do the echo here :

```
    if [ $1 ]
then
    temp=`sudo fuser $1/tcp 2> /dev/null | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
    echo 'The command '`cat /proc/$temp/cmdline`' use the port '$1
else
    echo "Give a port number"
fi
```

in one line like this :

```
if [ $1 ]
then

    echo 'The command '`cat /proc/`sudo fuser $1/tcp 2> /dev/null | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`/cmdline`' use the port '$1
else
    echo "Give a port number"
fi
```

But the shell interprets

```
`cat /proc/`
```

as a command (and this is normal i know it)

I just want to know if i can do this in one line without a temp variable

EDIT : now i have this

```
#!/bin/bash
RED='\033[0;33m'
NC='\033[0m'

#H
echo -e ${RED}'usePort.sh'${NC}
if [ $1 ]
then
    echo "The command $(cat /proc/$(sudo fuser $1/tcp 2> /dev/null | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)/cmdline) use the port $1"
else
    echo "Give a port number"
fi
```

The output is this :
`$ ./usePort.sh 22
usePort.sh
./usePort.sh: line 9: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
la commande /usr/sbin/sshd-D utilise le port 22`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [  -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "your commands"
    temp=$(sudo fuser "$1/tcp" 2> /dev/null | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
else
    echo "Give a port number"
fi
```

Avoid grace acents `` ` ``, instead you use `var=$( your_commands )`

Comment: okay, so when I use this : 
`echo 'The comand '$(cat /proc/$(sudo fuser $1/tcp 2> /dev/null | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)/cmdline)' use the port '$1`

the echo line have this in the interpreter : `line 10: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`

Comment: @HolyFredy it will not work, that way, because of single quote, use `echo "The command cat/proc/$temp/cmdline use the port $1"`

Comment: Even with `echo "The comand $(cat /proc/$(sudo fuser $1/tcp 2> /dev/null | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)/cmdline) use the port $1"` I have the same warning (note that the echo prompt correctly)

Comment: @HolyFredy: please read my comment, I have not suggested this

Comment: But i don't want to use a temp variable
the output will be like : `The command /usr/sbin/sshd-D use the port 22`

Comment: I want to show the command of the port that i gave when i call my .sh `usePort.sh 22` will give me : `The command /usr/sbin/sshd-D use the port 22` and I want to do the echo in one line just to know if it's possible without prompt warning. This is for knowledge, not to apply in a project, in that case i will use variable

Comment: @HolyFredy: to show command don't use `$( )`, this is to save output of command in variable, if you want to show with `$( your command )` then you have to escape it  `echo "\$(  my_command )"`

Comment: I don't want to show my command, I want to show the result of that command that use a result of a command (this is commandception)

Comment: To show result just use your variable like I showed above echo "$yourvariable"